# Nothing works past the index/main page. Am I missing anything?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I am currently migrating my website that was hosted on GoDaddy to an Amazon Linux instance. Everything has worked so far using elastic IP that I allocated, but I haven't been able to access other pages using the GoDaddy domain I transferred from my original website.

I have tried to change the site address/URL structure in the Wordpress settings, but I almost broke my website (TWICE!). Should I be changing one of the .htaccess files instead of the native Wordpress setting?

My elastic/public EC2 instance IP is: 52.26.232.168
The domain I would like to point to the IP is: artrantsbyaj.com.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I do not yet have a high enough reputation to post images yet, I apologize.

Comment: Have you tried saving the permalinks in the admin area>settings>permalinks

Comment: You transferred the DNS registry item, but DNS is not an instantaneous thing, it has to propagate, and invalidate. When did you transfer the domain? (the ip address now works)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your permalinks:

Go to the **permalink settings** and save them (do not change anything, only click on save to refresh your permalink structure).

Test it and let me know if you have any problem.

Regards.